# Rigging a non T-pose human mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

There is a non rigged human mesh, and I am trying to rig it. The problem is that it is not in T or A pose, but in an asymmetric, walking pose. Is there a way to rig it without editing the mesh? I know about the "Apply pose as rest pose" function, but after using it I cannot move armature back exactly into the original T pose (it is important for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

You can rig a model in any pose.  You just place the bones to match the model and weight it.  There's nothing built-in for armatures that makes them have to be specific poses; that's just a convenient way to make models.

But that doesn't mean that every mesh is appropriate for rigging, and a mesh that isn't rigged probably isn't appropriate.  This may be because it is a dynotopo sculpt, with too many vertices; it may be because it doesn't have a topology appropriate to armature deformation; it may be because it doesn't have enough vertex density at the joints to support deformation; it may be because certain parts of the model, where say an elbow is pressed firmly into the side, just don't have anything modeled for the hidden portions.

Comment: I didn't explain quite well the problem. The T-pose is a requirement of a program that will use the model. I have a pre-posed mesh, and I have to align the armature to match the pose, bind the mesh to it, then reset to exactly into the original T-pose. But now I can't do it, because after the "Apply pose as rest pose" the armature forget its original rest pose. I tried creating a pose into the pose library, but not working, as the bone transforms are relative to the rest pose, so if rest pose is changed, every poses in the pose lib are changed too.

Comment: An armature can't have more than one rest pose.  Yes, if you change the old rest pose, you will override the previous rest pose.  I think there's probably a more fundamental misunderstanding going on here, and reformulating your question into exactly what you are trying to achieve, and why you want to achieve that, would be helpful.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I know that only one rest position exists. This is the "origin" of the bone transform. My problem is that binding a mesh to an armature is only possible in the rest pose. To rig a mesh, for example a 3D scanned sculpture that is obviously not in T-pose (except if it is the Jesus monument in Rio de Janeiro), I need to rotate bones to match the mesh shape, then set this pose as rest pose. This is okay, but now I want to set the original pose (the T-pose), with the bound mesh. This last step is the one that I can't achieve.

Comment: You want to change the mesh to match the new armature rest pose?  I'll vote to close as duplicate and SE will make a link with the answer you're looking for.